# When will PostgreSQL execute archive_command to archive wal files?

Tags: postgresql

I use the `archive_command` below to archive WAL files. Suppose I have touched the file `archive_active` already. When will PostgreSQL execute the supplied `archive_command` to archive WAL files?

I know we can use the function `pg_switch_xlog()` to archive the WAL on demand, are there other trigger conditions?

PostgreSQL version: 9.3.0.

**--postgresql.conf**

```
archive_command = 'test ! -f /archive/pg93/archive_active || cp %p /archive/pg93/%f'
wal_level = hot_standby
archive_mode = on
```

**--archive directory**

```
[pg93@redhatB pg93]$ pwd
/archive/pg93

[pg93@redhatB pg93]$ ll
total 32M
-rw-------. 1 pg93 pg93 16M Oct 16 11:05 00000001000000000000007A
-rw-------. 1 pg93 pg93 16M Oct 16 11:07 00000001000000000000007B
-rw-rw-r--. 1 pg93 pg93   0 Oct 16 11:05 archive_active
```

Comment: What are the values for `wal_level` and `archive_mod`?

Comment: @MilenA.Radev, I edited the question, and add the wal_level and archive_mod .

Answer (score 17):

The archive command is executed every time it switches the archive log to a new one.
Which as you say can be triggered manually by calling the `pg_switch_xlog()` function.

Other than that, an archive log needs to be changed to a new one when it is full, which by default is when it reaches 16MB, but can be changed at compile time.

You can also specify a timeout value using the parameter `archive_timeout` which will execute the command after the set amount of seconds, which is useful for databases that have low activity.

*Update:*

Version 10 introduced a change that renames everything referencing "xlog" to "wal", so `pg_switch_xlog()` is now called `pg_switch_wal()`

Comment: pedantically, `archive_timeout` will only trigger `archive_command` if required (aka there was database activity)

Comment: Ran `select pg_switch_xlog()` and got `HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.`

Comment: Looks lile this function was removed in pg 10

Comment: Ok, [it was renamed](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/release-10.html) to `pg_switch_wal`

Comment: good point, I'll add a note about it

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan not sure what counts as "database activity" but with no writes it still triggers the archive command every interval.