# File creation dates of archived WAL files not in line with archive_timeout in PostgreSQL 9.6

Tags: postgresql, write-ahead-logging, docker, archive-log

I have configured `archive_timeout = 5` (i.e. 5 seconds) for a PostgreSQL 9.6 database in order to conduct tests around point-in-time recovery. My `archive_command` invokes `cp` into a local archive directory.

If I check the file modification dates in that local archive directory I see that WAL files are typically created in there only approx. every 20 seconds apart, i.e. far more than the configured 5 seconds. This is for PostgreSQL 9.6 running inside a Docker container on a lightly loaded system.

What could explain this large discrepancy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-wal.html#GUC-ARCHIVE-TIMEOUT) has an answer to this:

> When this parameter is greater than zero, the server will switch to a new segment file whenever this many seconds have elapsed since the last segment file switch, and there has been any database activity, including a single checkpoint (checkpoints are skipped if there is no database activity).

Based on your observation and the above quote, I guess you have a checkpoint every 20 seconds or so, and a very low rate of changes.

Comment: Yep, I guess that's true, the *and* in the cited documentation is important. Your answer is also backed up by [this comment](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/51589/141710): "pedantically, `archive_timeout` will only trigger `archive_command` if required (aka there was database activity)".